# How to run the current python script (forefront buffer) in Vim's command window?

Tags: python, vim

I want to run the python script (currently editing) in Vim's command window (do not want to switch to terminal). I am currently using this method - **:w !python**.

Are there any other methods available?

Comment: I like your edit. :P Much clearer.

Comment: Why does this method not suit you, Mr. fancy integral?